# How to retrieve property value in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, propertyinfo

I have an array like this :

```
var recordings = [];


  recordings.push({
    x: e.x,
    y: e.y,
    z: e.z
  });
```

How can I retrieve all the values to be displayed ?

I tried :

```
recordings.x;
recordings.y;
recordings.z;
```

but it does not work

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you put an Object into Array called recordings, you can't get value with `recordings.x` obviously, which is the way get value from Object.

If you want get value from Object,there is no need to push it into an array.

```
var e = { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, w:4, o:5 };
var recordings = {
    x: e.x,
    y: e.y,
    z: e.z
};
console.log(recordings.x);
```

Otherwise, you want get value from Array , what you need is for loop.

```
var e = { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, w:4, o:5 };
var recordings = [];
recordings.push({
    x: e.x,
    y: e.y,
    z: e.z
});
for(index in recordings){
    console.log(recordings[index].x);
    console.log(recordings[index].y);
    console.log(recordings[index].z);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.

Here's what I was looking for

```
for(var i = 0; i < recordings.length; i++){
    console.log("Recording " + i + ":");
    console.log("X: " + recordings[i].x);
    console.log("Y: " + recordings[i].y);
    console.log("Z: " + recordings[i].z);
}
```

Or

```
recordings[O].x;
recordings[1].x;
recordings[2].x;
recordings[3].x;
recordings[4].x;
```

Thank you all again

Both solutions makes me happy

Answer (score -1):

`recordings` is an array of objects. So if you want the first item, you will do it like this:

```
var firstItem = recordings[0];
firstItem.x;
firstItem.y;
firstItem.z;
```

If you want to loop through you array, you can do it like this:

```
recordings.forEach( function (item)
{
    var x = item.x;
    // Whatever else you need to do
});
```

Or like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < recordings.length; i++) 
{
    var x = recordings[i].x;
    // etc
}
```

Or if you want to use jQuery:

```
$.each(recordings, function(item) 
{
  var x = item.x
  // etc 
});
```